# Return values of sql into a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I have a SQL query, I use a foreach to return these values into a JSON array. Here is how my code looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(sales) from sales ... blah blah";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$output = array();

foreach(result as $row) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($output);
echo $json; // Returns the array
```

The array currently looks like this:

`[{"SUM(sales)}"."10000"},[{"SUM(sales)}"."51221"},[{"SUM(sales)}"."2351"}]`

I want it to be like this:
`[10000, 51221, 2351]`

When I use `decode($output)` it returns `NULL`.

Comment: does "sales" table have a "sales" column?

Comment: (*) If your sql has user input (like from a GET or POST var), then you need to change to using a prepared statement, execute, with fetch. Otherwise you are open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: What do you mean by `decode($output)` ? That isn't any php function I am aware of.

Comment: @derloopkat yes

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks for the note! It's actually an internal website.

Comment: @IncredibleHat the `json_decode($output)`, I meant. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$output = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    array_push($output, $row['SUM(sales)']);
}
$json = json_encode($output);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Giving some information about your solution will help a lot more to OP and to other people that visit SO, so please update your answer.

Comment: sure, i can do it tomorrow, currently I have a late evening

Comment: Also a way to make the row field selection clearer, is to adjust it in the SQL like so: `SELECT SUM(sales) as SumSales FROM sales ...` That way you can use `$row['SumSales']` (if thats more readable for you, personally I always name SUM() and COUNT(*) and the like).